# suexec AP_DOC_ROOT Path on gentoo

Tags: apache-2.2, gentoo, suexec, fcgi

after a few years running php as mod_php I want to move to fcgi. On my server I run currently gentoo linux. I allready set up php als fcgi and everything is working.

But there is one problem. I have to change the path of the AP_DOC_ROOT from /var/www to /home/www. On ubuntu there is something like apache2-suexec-custom, but how can I do it on gentoo? Or do I have to recompile apache myself?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found the solution. There is an Option / Env Variable, that can be set:

```
 * You can manipulate several configure options of suexec
  * through the following environment variables:
  *
  *  SUEXEC_SAFEPATH: Default PATH for suexec (default: '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin')
  *   SUEXEC_LOGFILE: Path to the suexec logfile (default: '/var/log/apache2/suexec_log')
  *    SUEXEC_CALLER: Name of the user Apache is running as (default: apache)
  *   SUEXEC_DOCROOT: Directory in which suexec will run scripts (default: '/var/www')
  *    SUEXEC_MINUID: Minimum UID, which is allowed to run scripts via suexec (default: 1000)
  *    SUEXEC_MINGID: Minimum GID, which is allowed to run scripts via suexec (default: 100)
  *   SUEXEC_USERDIR: User subdirectories (like /home/user/html) (default: public_html)
  *     SUEXEC_UMASK: Umask for the suexec process (default: 077)
```